# batch / vbs message box to display variables

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have this code to make a message box. How do I make the message display 4 variables

```
%data1%
%data2%
%data3%
%data4%
```

-

```
Taskkill /f /im wscript.exe 2>> Log.txt 
If exist "%Temp%\done.vbs" (
 Attrib -R -S -H "%Temp%\done.vbs"
 If exist "%Temp%\done.vbs" (
  Echo Could not delete file "%Temp%\done.vbs"
  Pause
 )
)
> "%Temp%\done.vbs" ECHO x=msgbox("The message" ,6, "test")
start "" wscript "%temp%\done.vbs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your aproach should work but there are a few syntax errors in your code.
try something like

```
echo msgbox %data1% > %temp%\done.vbs
start "" wscript "%temp%\done.vbs"
```

use the right amount of quotes and check the documentation of msgbox

hope that helps